# ddl is not updated in server - asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I work on ASP.NET c#. I have a  DropDownList.  (runat="server")

On $(document).ready, I updated its value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
document.getElementById("ddl").value = "abc";
…
```

When I get back to the Server (c#), there is no value in the ddl:

```
ddl.SelectedValue == ""
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks,

YYY

Comment: Check the console for errors.  Your ID is probably wrong.

Comment: We need to see your html as well, to be able to help, as setting a value to a "drop down" might not work how you do it.

Comment: Is this web forms? I guess you need document.getElementById("<%= ddl.ClientID %>") instead

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy it right!!!!
I used the RIGHT id, and saw that in the client side - my ddl had the correct value.
Still, the value in the server remained "".
When should it be updated?

Comment: @Yael please edit your question appropriately, add server-side code and markup of the ddl

Comment: Thank you all, I found a solution: after I changed the value, I fired the change() event of the ddl (in my javascript code), and that solved my problem :)

Comment: It works now: I updated the ddl value in document.ready event,
and after that I fired the change() event of the ddl, so the dll value got updated in the server :)

Answer (score 1):

as far your dropdown runat="server" it has generated ClientID, "ddl" it's serverside id, on client you need to call like shown below

```
document.getElementById("<%= ddl.ClientID %>").value = "abc";
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of WebForms: in the list of things this framework screws up is ID's of your runat="server" elements
When the engine processes your server markup it generates own id's based on the place where you declared that particular element. Check it in your browser devtools.

Luckily since **ASP.NET 4** you can specify special attribute **ClientIDMode** and now you can do it like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

which will render like

```
<input id="txt" name="ctl00$MasterPageBody$ctl00$txt" />
```

If you cannot use for some reason ASP.NET 4, you can stick to old solution as @Dan proposed:

```
document.getElementById("<%= ddl.ClientID %>")
```

But this is not the recommended way.

**EDIT**

Probably you should do `ddl.SelectedItem.Value` instead.

Comment: I can't find any reference where `<%= ddl.ClientID %>` is discouraged for any reason other than some people thinking that it is ugly. Do you have a reference for why it is not recommended? It is actually probably recommended most often.

Comment: What is better? Everytime we need to reference to an element we have to use this clumsy construct or maybe save its value in some variable and use it further (and have +1 state in our code). Or we may specify this attribute only once and reference to that element in sane classical way as web developers with various background got used to.

Comment: Moreover the less server templating we use the faster a page renders. Maybe the win is marginal but it's still a win.